# URI typed attributes in CoreData: how to query with NSPredicate

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a CoreData-Entity that stores an attribute called "imageUrl" of type "URI".
It's used to store URL's (as in Swift URL / NSURL) for eg. rendering remote images.

How would I query for the string representation of an URI-type attribute?

---

Example: I'd like to get all objects that match `"http://mydomain.jpg"` or `URL(string: "http://mydomain.jpg")` to be more precise.

For attributes that are "String"-typed this would be sufficient:

`NSPredicate(format: "myStringAttribute LIKE %@", "http://mydomain.jpg")`

Would the following work for URI-type attributes?

`NSPredicate(format: "imageUrl LIKE %@", URL(string: "http://mydomain.jpg"))`

Comment: It should work, since the URI type is a `URL` according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsattributedescription/attributetype

Comment: `LIKE` assumes a string comparison so use `=` instead to compare `URL` objects.

Comment: @Larme thx, thats a useful reference!
@JoakimDanielson Thx for spotting.

I was able to succesfully query with `NSPredicate(format: "imageUrl = %@", imageUrl as CVarArg)`, since XCode complained that URL doesn't conform to CVarArg.

Comment: You could also `NSPredicate(format: "imageUrl = %@", argumentArray: [imageUrl])` to avoid the cast. Side note, I would even use `%K` to avoid typo: `NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(YourEntityClass.imageUrl), imageUrl])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering to not let that question without an answer, but in my opinion, we three [@nylki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2921415/nylki) (the author), [@Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) and myself answered it together. I'll mark it as "Community Wiki" then.

`URI` in CoreData is a for `URL` objects. It's written as such in the documentation of [`NSAttributeDescription.AttributeType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsattributedescription/attributetype) for the [`NSAttributeDescription.AttributeType.uri`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsattributedescription/attributetype/3747504-uri).

`LIKE` keyword in the predicate is for String comparison as stated by the [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) documentation, so we need to use `=` instead.

So the answer is:

```
NSPredicate(format: "imageUrl = %@", imageUrl as CVarArg)
```

Or

```
NSPredicate(format: "imageUrl = %@", argumentArray: [imageUrl])
```

if we don't want to use the as `CVarArg`.

A better way to avoid typo would be to use `%K` placeholder which is for `%K is a var arg substitution for a key path.`. Combined to `#keyPath()`:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(YourEntityClass.imageUrl), imageUrl])
```

That way, if we wrote by error `"imageUrI = %@"` with an uppercase `i` instead of `l` that with might not see, we ensure the path.